# Multiple Tab Detection

Tags: javascript

I want to know that if it is possible to detect how many tab are open in a browser window if I am on server side and want to detect whether the user using site hosted by my server has opened more than 1 tab (of some other site than hosted by my server ) in browser.

Comment: Other than the method described by Scimonster below, No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only possible to keep track of how many times your site has been opened. Keep a cookie with the number of active tabs open. `onload`, increment the number in the cookie. `onunload`, decrement it. The server should then be able to read this cookie, and know how many instances are open.

Comment: Actually i want to know whether it is possible to detect any opened tab in browser other than tab of site hosted by my server.

Comment: Nope, no access to other sites/tabs.

Comment: @user2912611 That would be a serious privacy violation. BTW, relating to this answer, make sure to use a *session* cookie.